# Flutter CupertinoNavBar make leading content expand?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to make CupertinoNavBar leading widget Expand:

[image]

Currently, it fixed leading width, even make middle to be None, it still fix.

I know this is opposite with Apple Design princeples but there many APP such as Facebook messenger using same design.

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

I was seeing this problem and decided to look for the source code.
I found that it can be solved by changing the value of the maxWidth(by default is 300) to a bigger one inside navigation_toolbar.dart, line 113, class _ToolbarLayout and function performLayout.
But it's not a good idea to change an inbuilt class, so I recommend to change it in a copy of those classes.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Changing an inbuilt class is not a good option. Because whenever an update is done it will overwrite the changes. Instead it should be extended to work differently or edit by copying the whole widget.

Comment: Yep,this is a temporary solution ,but is a nice idea to copy whole widget class and change it there.